# React emotion CSS - template literal returning function not value

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, emotion

I've been trying to get this logic to work with react emotion, using a prop passed to this component to render my CSS. But the animation CSS property is ignored - I think it is because the way I have done this means that the function is returned for the animation property string, not the value.

Can anyone help me to do the right syntax for this?

```js
import React from "react";
import { css } from "emotion";

const strike = keyframes`
  from{
    transform: scaleX(0)
  }
  to{
    transform : scaleX(1)
  }
`;

const todoStyle = css`
cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 200px; */
  &:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    top: 50%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    animation: ${strike} 0.3s ${props => (props.todo.complete === false ? " normal" : " reverse")};
  }
`;

// everything works except the animation property above is ignored

export default props => (
  <div className={todoStyle} onClick={props.toggleComplete}>
    {props.todo.text}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `animation: ${strike} 0.3s ${props => ...}` in `todoStyle`, emotion will have no idea what props is - I'm surprised that nothing throws an error.

You can try moving the props function inside the component:

```
  export default props => (
-   <div className={todoStyle} onClick={props.toggleComplete}>

+   <div className={css`
+     ${todoStyle}
+     animation: ${strike} 0.3s ${props => (!props.todo.complete ? "normal" : "reverse")};
+     `} onClick={props.toggleComplete}>

      {props.todo.text}
    </div>
  );
```